# How to add and use (signature/system level) permission in an Android application

Tags: android-manifest, android-permissions

I created an application with Android reflection on "android-21" but the problem now is adding the permission in the Manifest file as after adding the permission manually in the "Manifest.xml", an error received in the catlogs while trying to run the application saying that the no permission for

```
android.permission.READ_PRECISE_PHONE_STATE
```

After checking I found that this permission's level has been changed from "dangerous" to "signature/system" and has a comment "Pending API council approval".

Is there a way to get the permission or even to get reflection for the original Android Manifest file.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the only way how to be eligible for a signature level permission is to be (the APK) signed with the same certificate as the system image. Or rather the app/component which exposes the permission. (Which is Android/System in this case).

There might be apps out there with that permission in manifest, but that doesn't necessarily mean they also actually get the permission granted! As this was treated differently in the past, those apps might no be updated, or they just might be wrong implemented.

Comment: @Adss: No way as a 3rd party developer.

Answer (score 2):

This permission is in limbo, could be removed from public use, when that happens those apps are no longer good. So you should not request it in the manifest.